# Embedding YouTube Video with jQuery Templates - C#

Tags: jquery, youtube, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery Templates to Embed user posted YouTube vids. I am able to fetch the video id and save it into the database and everything is working correctly. However when trying to embed the video with jQuery Templates as follows:

```
{{if streamObj.TypeOf == 3}}
            <object width="425" height="350" data='http://www.youtube.com/v/${VideoId}' type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            <param name="src" value='http://www.youtube.com/v/${VideoId}' /></object>
{{else}}
```

I get the following error: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.youtube.com/v/"`

`${VideoId}` and `streamObj.TypeOf` return correctly. But that's the error.
What could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: The error message showing the youtube url is missing the video id (`http://www.youtube.com/v/`). Are you sure the placeholder `${VideoId}` gets replaced ?

Comment: Are you sure that ${VideoId} is not an empty string ?

Comment: open firebug or some other javascript console to check if the url is being generated after the page has loaded. your VideoId might be getting reset somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<object width="425" height="350" data='http://www.youtube.com/v/' + ${VideoId} type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="src" value='http://www.youtube.com/v/' + ${VideoId} />
</object>
```

Or perhaps better.

```
var videoUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + ${VideoId};

<object width="425" height="350" data=videoUrl type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="src" value=videoUrl />
</object>
```

I believe that the template tag in your code isn't evaluated corretly due to the fact that the template tag is set as a part of a js string value.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the `${VideoId}` out of string and use a string operation like

```
var videoIdString=${videoId};

var urlString='http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoIdString ;
```

Because :

in this page , ive never seen ${} used between quotes .

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/

so your code would be :

```
var videoIdString=${videoId};

<object width="425" height="350" data='http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoIdString
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="src" value='http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoIdString /></object>
```